# Accessing raw image bytes from iPhone to computer

Tags: ios, image, file, byte, gpuimage

I am doing image processing on the iPhone, but I need to get the raw bytes outside of cocoa so I can optimise the algorithm on a more image friendly platform like Matlab. I am using Brad Larson's excellent GPUIMAGE and can get the raw bytes no problem, but when I use NSData writetofile method the text file obtained (which I get by downloading the app from xcode organiser which gives me access to the file in the documents folder) is in a strange format. I am a Matlab programmer so I'm relatively new to cocoa, so I reckon I'm must be missing something basic as I imagine I may be able to just use c functions to print to a file.

Any discussions I have found only involve reading and writing within cocoa and the app sandbox. I also could probably use the GpuImageMovieWriter but I imagine AVAssetWriter compresses the image data, and I need the uncompressed raw bytes. It doesn't matter what way the bytes are organised as I can parse it easily in matlab.

So basically what is the easiest way to get say an outputted txt or csv file that looks like say 124,255,0,166,255 etc etc (i.e image ints) from the cocoa environment. I had a similar problem before designing an accelerometer algorithm where in the end I just printed the raw data to the console copied to a text file and then parsed in matlab, however given that I'm dealing in images now this is not practical.

Any help in this matter, pointers to relevant text etc, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, that's not a text file you're writing out. It's the binary representation of the raw bytes of the image. You can't treat it as a text file.

The structure of the image data is simple, with each pixel represented as one set of four bytes. Each byte is a 0-255 color component value, in the order of blue, green, red, and alpha. The image is scanned from left to right, top to bottom, so you just need to know the width of the image in pixels to figure out how things loop around. From that, it should be easy to import into whatever application you want.

Comment: Thanks Brad for the clarification about the binary file, my lack of understanding concerned the nature of the file, I'm not usually down at such a low level when it comes to files. I used fread in matlab instead of other import options and that worked a treat. I must also take this opportunity to thank you for all that I have learned from you regarding iPhone development both here in stack overflow, your lectures online and your generous open source material.